# Stack Exchange Android app crashes when unable to connect

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

At work I have pretty poor internet connection on my phone. Because of this, sometimes when I try to use the Android app it fails to connect. Instead of this being handled nicely, the Android Stack Exchange application displays a black screen for a few seconds then crashes completely.

[image: Initial Screen]

[image: Black Screen]

[image: Crash Screen]

Not sure if this is a version-specific bug, but I'm experiencing this on Android 4.4.4 with CyanogenMod 11.0-XNPH44S.

Comment: Yep, but for me it doesn't crash, only fades into the black screen and... nothing else (using SGS5 with Android 4.4).

Comment: I just downloaded the Android app and am getting this exact same error message with an excellent wifi connection and no problems with my other apps. I suspect it's a problem with the app. I only found out yesterday that the Android app existed. Is it new?

Comment: Well, last time I observed this problem, [it didn't crash, but nothing load](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256627/improve-responsiveness-information-of-stack-exchange-app-when-theres-a-proble), so not sure if it's still repro'able or not...

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with either wifi off or all requests failing.

Answer (score 2):

Tap `Report`. Those reports are being sent to Google Play so developers can get crash information and, hopefully, fix it.

Comment: I don't know. I feel reporting it here would be more beneficial than reporting it through Google Play. That and the reason I had this problem in the first place was because I had no internet connection.

Comment: I doubt Android devs of SE read it here, but you did not include the crash report anyway :-)

Comment: Yep, thats a good way. But do you really think that SE Android Devs don't look there at all? Of course they do! They implement requests and fix the bugs. Browse through [tag:android-app] questions and read the description of this tag.