# Question not found after posting a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I just posted a question on Meta.SE, but after tapping on it, the app says 'Question not found'. I went to Safari and opened the question with no difficulties, came back and the issue still persisted.

It may be notable that it was the second post I made in the one mobile session, without closing or terminating the session.

[image: q not found]

I'm running this on an iPhone 6+ with iOS 9.2 and version 1.4.1 of the SE app.

I posted a question on Meta.SE from my phone, went back to the feed, saw the bug the photo reported, went to report it, posted the question, and immediately it presented me with that, hitting ok and tapping back to the meta.se feed before tapping the question, which resulted in the same response again. I repeated that process about 5 times, and still nothing.

I deleted the specific post in the photo, however that is unrelated (done hours later), and the time of reporting, it had no ups, no comments, no dupe flags and was fine.

Comment: Can you provide more steps as to how you got the error?  Did you ask the question and immediately see this error, or did you leave the question, see it in the question list and try viewing again?

Comment: Also, not sure if this is related, but that specific post it deleted and deleted posts are not visible to the app.  You may still have items in your feed or notifications related to the deleted question that would lead you to this screen on tap.

Comment: No, it deleted a few hours after reporting, that's unrelated

Comment: I'll edit a little more description into my question.

Comment: This has happened to me three or four times now, most recently just now on [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120727/can-wands-burn). Eventually the app stops claiming the question does not exist, but if I recall correctly, it persists after force-quitting and reopening the app. I can't think of anything I've done differently the times I've had this appear as opposed to the times when my questions have gone through without a glitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.6.

[As I describe in the Android version of this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245618/this-question-is-not-available-it-may-have-been-deleted-when-submitting-a-que/277404#277404), there's a delay between when questions are written and when they are readable and a caching issue that keeps them hidden.

The solution we were supposedly applying was to not load the question at all when displaying it, but instead show the question that was just created.  Turns out we had too many code paths handling that process which meant sometimes the full question wasn't getting through.

As part of some other bug fixes I've consolidated things down to a single path (well 2 if you count iPad's slightly different container) and fixed the various issues that would force the question to load from the server.