# Improve responsiveness & information of Stack Exchange app when there's a problem with the connection to the server

Tags: feature-request, android-app

On May 17, around 12pm UTC, the Stack Exchange app for Android couldn't load anything (the feed, questions, notifications). Perhaps it's related to [SE data center's switching IP](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3454597#3454597) affecting SE API, I can't tell. The problem is, there's no visual indicator if the server is "down" or problem with your connection. When I tried opening the app, it became very sluggish:

[image: splash screen freezes] [image: black screen!]

<sup>The spinning indicator froze, followed by black screen of unresponsiveness</sup>

Pressing the back button while on black screen froze the app (related to UI thread). After a while (around 30 seconds), it went to the feeds. Same thing happened:

[image: trying to load the feed...]

<sup>Trying to load the feed... (note the light blue spinning indicator)</sup>

After a while again (around 30 seconds)... the loading stopped, and there's nothing shown!

[image: empty feed]

It looked confusing. The app didn't crash, but it didn't load anything. I thought there's a problem with my connection (at that time, I was using 3G), but I could browse other sites. Force-closing and reopening the app didn't fix it. After checking with the Taverners, there's when I found out that there's a server issue (mentioned above).

Avid SE users may realize to check [StackStatus](https://www.stackstatus.net/) or its [Twitter feeds](http://twitter.com/StackStatus), but I don't think general users will know that, and instead thinking "this app is broken!".

Other than improving the responsiveness when the app cannot connect to the server, I propose to show an informative message on the feeds when it fails to load, maybe similar like this:

[image: stackstatus on app]

<sup>[StackEgg](http://stackexchange.github.io/stackegg/) image is courtesy of Stack Exchange</sup>

> Uh oh, it seems there's a problem when trying to connect to Stack Exchange server.
>
> [Tap here to try again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256627/improve-responsiveness-information-of-stack-exchange-app-when-theres-a-proble), or [check StackStatus](https://www.stackstatus.net/).

Tested on:

- Stack Exchange app: v1.0.62
- Connection: 3G and WiFi

Comment: Huge +1 on this. Thanks for putting all the effort you did to make this request, it'll definitely be implemented.